# Python Pass-By-Object-Reference in memory using id()

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing

I am trying to test out some code in reference to [Robert Heaton's article](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) explaining the difference between the different concepts of passing parameters into functions.

Why are list and myList stored in the same location in memory when, according to Heaton, they should be two completely separate variables.

Here is what I have written:

```
def main():
    myList = [0]
    print(f"myList: {id(myList)}")
    print(f"[0]: {id([0])}")
    append(myList)
    print(f"After call: {myList}")


def append(list):
    print(f"append's list: {id(list)}")
    list.append(1)
```

According to Heaton, with pass-by-object-reference "the function provides its own box and creates a new variable for itself". As such, I expected that id(myList) and id(list) should be two different variables stored in different locations in memory.

However, the output I receive is:

```
myList: 1941960670528
[0]: 1941963219200
append's list: 1941960670528
After call: [0, 1]
```

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. A Python variable is a name for an object, not a named location in memory. Objects can (and often are) referred to by multiple names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider the entire paragraph. The article is not saying it should be 2 different objects. There is one list, but separate variables pointing to it.

Consider the following
(`list` variable changed to `l` because built-ins shouldn't be used for variable names.):

```
def append(l):
    print(f"append's list: {id(l)}")
    l.append(1)
    l = []
    print(f"append's list after reassigning: {id(l)}")

myList = [0]
print(f"myList: {id(myList)}")
append(myList)
print(f"After call: {myList}")
print(f"myList id after call: {id(myList)}")
```

We reassigned `l` to a new list, and yet `myList` outside is still pointing to the list containing `[0, 1]`

What it's essentially trying to show, is that there are 3 parts to a variable - a name, reference and its value.
*Names* - e.g. `l`, `myList` - is what we refer to in code. They, in turn get resolved to a *reference* - to simplify, the value given by `id()` - to find a place in memory where the actual *value* is stored.
So, when we pass a list to a function, **same reference** is given a **new name** we can use inside the function. Changing the value related to this reference will be visible to the outside function, as the reference is the same. If we do something that changes the reference, e.g. assign a new list with `l = []`, this will not affect the outside list, as it still uses the old reference.

To summarise, we've got 2 relationships: name -> reference and reference -> value

When calling a function, we give the reference a new name, resulting in something like:

```
name_outer -\
             >- reference -- value
name_inner -/
```

Changing the value results in
something like:

```
name_outer -\
             >- reference -- new_value
name_inner -/
```

While changing the reference results in:

```
name_outer  --  reference   --   value

name_inner -- new_reference -- new_value
```

Comment: Why is that if I id() the variable name and id() the value, they give two different references?

Comment: Because they **are** 2 different references - every time you create a new object, it gets a unique reference, regardless if it shares a value with existing object or no (there are small exceptions with `string`s and `int`s to save memory, but they are just that - exceptions) Doing `id([])` de facto creates a new list with its own reference, but without giving it any name. You're not `id`ing the value, you are `id`ing object that happens to have the same value as the other variable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (but maybe I was taught a different terminology), the article is wrong when it says Python has a special function call schema. Python uses call-by-value, which simply means (to the extent of my knowledge) that a function call like `f(x)` copies the bits of the value of `x` into the value of the formal argument of `f` (ie. in a register or on the stack).

What makes it behave as described is that Python values are actually pointers to memory region containing the actual object. A variable corresponds to a memory location (for instance, it could be "the register `rcx`", or "7 bytes above the location pointed by address in `rbp`") which indicates where the pointer actually is.

Note that this behavior is the same as in other languages that hide pointers and memory management, such as Java, OCaml or Smalltalk. Even with this schema of compilation, it is not always true that a value is always a pointer to a region of the memory where the actual data is stored: indeed, if we consider immutable data that has the same size as a pointer, one might be tempted not to allocate a machine word somewhere on the heap for this data. This can considerably complicate the GC logic, but is implemented for integers in OCaml for instance.

The explanation of @matszwecja as to what happens in your example seems correct to me, so I won't repeat it here.

Also, as a side note, the specification of Python doesn't tell that `id` leaks the address pointed by the value of a variable. It's just the current implementation that does it like that, because it satisfies the spec, but that won't work in Jython or PyPy for instance.